How to create a bash alias with a name that includes an argument
What I want to achieve is to change the default behavior of a command + argument, specifically tail -f. This command shows, by default, the last 10 lines of the file and follows its changes. I want it to show 50 lines, instead of 10. The corresponding command for that is tail -fn 50 so I thought about creating an alias with something like this:
alias 'tail -f'='tail -fn 50'

But it doesn't work.
Is there a way to create an alias with a command + argument 'name' to substitute the original command?
How can I achieve this, if not?

Rule number #1 of aliases: forget about them until functions fail you.

I used an alias to present the problem, I suspected it was not the ideal solution but I used it as an example of what I wanted to achieve. It was obvious some smarty would vote down, not help, but there's always somebody willing to help.

I didn't downvote, as I don't think the question warranted it. But did you try writing a function to do what you wanted first?

I didn't mean you downvoted, I just mention it.

It's very difficult to do that sort of thing with an alias, but it's trivial with a function.  That's good, because you should have replaced all your aliases with functions 20 years ago!  To get the behavior you're asking for, you could do:
tail() { case $1 in -f) shift; set -- -fn 50 "$@"; esac; command tail "$@"; }


I don't think it's even possible to do this with an alias, not in the sense I think the OP wants. Only the first word of a command is subject to alias expansion, and the expansion is insensitive to the other words in the command.

It worked. Great answer!

If you try your approach, you should get an error message
bash: alias: `tail -f': invalid alias name

at least if you have a not-too-old bash version (If I remember correctly, very old bash allowed you to define such an alias, but you couldn't call it). The reason is that a space is not a valid character in an alias name.
Hence you first have to think about a valid name for the alias:
alias tail-f='tail -fn 50'

Now you can execute
tail-f FILENAME

while a
tail -f FILENAME

would still exhibit the original behaviour of tail.
